# Windows Batch Script: For ... in loop to capture program output not working

Tags: windows-7, batch-file, windows-server-2008-r2

I have a batch script setup to automatically retrieve a file from a remote FTP server. Part of the requirement is the file will be named with a new datestamp each day, such as "File_90611.csv." I have a command line tool that generates the filename; which is then supposed to be set to a variable using the line below:

```
for /f "delims=" %a in ('C:\BIN\YesterdayDateStamp.exe') do @set DATESTAMP=%a
```

The problem is this. This line works fine when run from the command line directly. However, when I put this exact same line in a batch script and run it; I get this error:

\BIN\YesterdayDateStamp.exe') was unexpected at this time.

I REM'ed everything out in the script except the FOR ... IN commands to make sure there wasn't some sort of conflict; but even with this I still get an error.

Been Googling for an answer but have no leads. Any ideas? Any constructive input is greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
Frank

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When `for` is used in a batch file, you need to double the percent signs in front of the variable name.

From `for /?`:

> To use the FOR command in a batch program, specify %%variable instead
>   of %variable.  Variable names are case sensitive, so %i is different
>   from %I.